# Random forbidden (403) responses from http calls

Tags: android, apache, http

I'm doing a lot of http calls in my Android application.  The http calls are synchronous for the most part.  Every once in a while I'll get many 403 forbidden responses in a row, hitting the same URL.  I do a login call directly before the call that results in a 403.  The login call returns 200 ok.  The 403s also happen more on newer Android platforms.

How I'm creating the client:

```
    // Create and initialize HTTP parameters
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 200);
    ConnPerRoute cpr = new ConnPerRoute() {
        public int getMaxForRoute(HttpRoute httpRoute) {
            return 50;
        }
    };
    ConnManagerParams.setMaxConnectionsPerRoute(params, cpr);
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    // Create and initialize scheme registry 
    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

    // Create an HttpClient with the ThreadSafeClientConnManager.
    ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);
    _client = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
```

The http call:

```
CookieStore cookie_store = HttpSupport.getCookieStoreInstance();   
HttpContext http_context = HttpSupport.getHttpContextInstance(); 
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(StaticFields.DEVICES_RESOURCE);
http_context.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookie_store);
response = client.execute(get, http_context);
status_code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

I'm using a static CookieStore and HttpContext contained in my class HttpSupport.

Comment: You may be running into some anti-DDOS security system designed to keep you from overloading a server, so it maybe be an issue with the server in question and not with your code.

Comment: I checked with IT and they said they didn't think we have any of that in place.  I have to check with one other person before I can be sure.

Comment: Our server doesn't have anything that would return a 403 due to overloading the server.